# Get the version of the Knockout.js from browser console?

Tags: knockout.js, console

Is there a way to get the Knockout version from the browser console ? I have managed to get the jQuery and the Bootstrap version from the browser console. But I have not seen any way to get the Knockout version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just searched the [konockout.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.0/knockout-debug.js) file for the version and you can access it using `ko.version`

```js
console.log(ko.version)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```